# How to amend time format of comments, using child-theme?

Tags: comments, date-time, formatting

How to amend (override) the time format of the comments (of the posts and pages), not touching the wordpress initial installation? I use a child theme and if it is possible in any way to do it from the child theme to prevent my changes been overwritten by the next WP update.
I would prefer to use add_filter()

I am trying to use:

```
// define the get_comment_time callback 
function filter_get_comment_time( $date, $d, $gmt, $translate, $comment ) { 
    $d = "g:i:s";
    return $d; 
}; 

// add the filter 
add_filter( 'get_comment_time', 'filter_get_comment_time', 10, 5);
```

But it returns only the string "g:i:s".

WP 4.9.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return the formatted date string, the following will work:

```
// define the get_comment_time callback 
function filter_get_comment_time( $date, $d, $gmt, $translate, $comment ) { 
  $d = "g:i:s";
  $date = mysql2date($d, $date, $translate);
  return $date;
}; 

// add the filter 
add_filter( 'get_comment_time', 'filter_get_comment_time', 10, 5);
```

Comment: Dear @Pabamato, thank you for your kind answer! It has solved the issue! Many thanks!

Comment: The only thing I cannot get is that why WP does not check the GLOBAL date and time format, set in the General settings? I have set them to g:i:s and everywhere it works ecross the site, but only the comments...

Comment: Hi @Arsenii, thanks for your warm feedback. I don't see a reason for not getting the global time format setting, do you have a custom comments template in your theme? As always if you want to go to the main source for the issue you can try deactivating all the plugins and/or switching to a diff theme, just to make sure there is nothing else filtering the time string result.

Comment: Dear @Pabamato, thank you for your kind answer! yes, I found yesterday, that it came out to be because of a custom template in the theme.. I did need to make a custom copy of that template in the child-theme and everything got better! Thank you!